# Ajax powered form submission working only once Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-views

I have this blog application where I want to give a preview button, that saves the form and then opens the blog in a new window. The javascript for that is

```
  $(function() {
    var current_link = location.href;

    $(".preview_button").click(function() 
    {           
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: current_link,
          data: $("#blog_form").serialize(),
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) 
          {
            window.open(data,'preview_tab');
            $("#reply-message").html('Form saved');
          },
          error: function(request,error) 
          {
            $("#reply-message").html('Form not saved because error:' + error);
          },

        });

        return false;   
    });
  }

);
```

I am processing this in views.py as

```
 if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method == 'POST':

            author = User.objects.get(pk=author_id)
            blog = get_object_or_404(Entry, creator = author, slug = slug)

            title = request.POST.get('title', False)
            text = request.POST.get('text', False)
            tags = request.POST.get('tags', False)
            enable_comments = request.POST.get('enable_comments', False)

            blog.title = title
            blog.text = text
            blog.tags = tags
            blog.enable_comments = enable_comments

            blog.save()

            return_message = '/blogs/' + str(blog.creator.id) + '/' + str(blog.slug) + '/' + 'preview/' 
            return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(return_message),mimetype='application/javascript')
```

The `return_message` contains the url of the preview page and is used to open it in new window. I am having two problems

1. **The form is being submitted only once, using this javascript, to submit again I have to refresh the page.**
2. **Secondly all the fields of the blog are being updated, except the textarea. I fail to understand why this could be happening**

**Edit: Reason for the problem**

1. The first problem is because the same csrf token is being send when I serialize the form, so is there a way I can remove this token from the serialize function?
2. The second problem is because I am using TinyMCE editor on the text area and when I type something in the editor the changes are not reflected back to the actual text box. How can I pick the text from the text editor and not from the underlying (most probably) hidden text area

Comment: Sorry, don't know, but you may want to remove the trailing comma after your error handler - some browsers won't like it. Maybe you could post some of your HTML?

Answer (score 2):

Problem 1 sounds like it could be related to Django's built-in [CSRF protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/). Try inspecting the HTTP requests with a tool like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and check to see if the same CSRF token is being sent twice. Unless CSRF protection has been explicitly disabled for a view, the form submission would be rejected the second time around unless the token is updated.

[The docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax) have a section on dealing with this in Ajax code.

Although I couldn't say for sure, perhaps it's possible that Problem 2 has to do with jQuery's selection process for which fields it includes when it serializes. From [their docs](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

> Note: Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No
>   submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted
>   using a button. For a form element's value to be included in the
>   serialized string, the element must have a name attribute. Values from
>   checkboxes and radio buttons (inputs of type "radio" or "checkbox")
>   are included only if they are checked. Data from file select elements
>   is not serialized.

Comment: I think the first problem is because of the same csrf token being sent twice. When I serialize the form the csrf token also gets serialized and since the page is not reloaded the csrf token is the same. Since I have added the javascript file that you have pointed me to, can you tell me how can I remove the csrf token from the serialized data

Comment: As for the second problem, the text area does have a name attribute so the problem should not be because of that, however the text area has a `class="mceEditor"` which makes it a TinyMCE editor so could that be causing a problem???